# Which Namespace holds Component.For in Castle Windsor?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm learning Castle Windsor and I found [this tutorial](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/basic-tutorial.md).  In it, there's this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // CREATE A WINDSOR CONTAINER OBJECT AND REGISTER THE INTERFACES, AND THEIR CONCRETE IMPLEMENTATIONS.
    var container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.Register(Component.For<Main>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IDependency1>().ImplementedBy<Dependency1>());
    container.Register(Component.For<IDependency2>().ImplementedBy<Dependency2>());

    // CREATE THE MAIN OBJECT AND INVOKE ITS METHOD(S) AS DESIRED.
    var mainThing = container.Resolve<Main>();
    mainThing.DoSomething();
}
```

I'm following along with this, but the `Component.For` calls are throwing compiler errors for me.  Intellisense can't find `Component`.  What namespace should I be using for this call?

I added the `Castle.Core` and `Castle.Windsor` references via NuGet.  I've been searching through the object browser trying to find `Component`, but it's a pretty common name.  The tutorial inconveniently left out* the `using`s and I can't find any documentation.

* *I find that a lot of tutorials and StackOverflow answers leave out the `using`s and I can never figure out why.*

Comment: If you have a few minutes, please send in a pull request for the tutorial to include the required namespaces, you can just edit the markdown file on GitHub.com.

Comment: @JonathonRossi sorry I'm not really familiar with GitHub.  I got the Castle Windsor libraries from NuGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `Castle.MicroKernel.Registration`.

That does annoy me too sometimes, though if the project is open source, it's usually easy enough to search [their repository](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/016730de012f15985410fb33e2eb907690fe5a28/src/Castle.Windsor/MicroKernel/Registration/Component.cs).